# Outlook Calendar API Without User Sign-in

Tags: authentication, outlook, office365, office365api

I'm trying to integrate Microsoft Outlook Calendar API responses into my site using a company calendar, not the users calendar. The API's I've been looking at require the user to sign-in so they can then approve access to their calendar, but I don't need to access their calendars https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#GetEvents. I'm wanting to access the company's calendar so I'm trying to find a way to have the company's admin sign-in once to allow this to happen, or for sign-in to not be required at all. Basically I'm building a booking form where the visitor to the site selects an appointment from a dropdown menu which has been populated with appointments from the company's Outlook calendar through a GET request. The selection is then sent as a POST update method to insert the booked appointment into the company's calendar. Can anyone recommend a way for me to go about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here in documentation explains how you can get access without a user
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: Thank you heaps, this is useful. I'm using Outlook Calendar API's, not Microsoft Graph API's but hopefully I can get access following these same steps but with different Permissions and API's.

Comment: Why are you using Outlook API over Graph? Graph is the replacement for Outlook API and is the recommended path for all new development.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise it was the replacement, I thought it was an alternative and Graph was used for more out of the box apps built using Microsoft services. TBH I've gone down a worm hole with all the Microsoft documentation and gotten myself confused over which services to use. But if I can use Microsoft Graph API's with my own app (not one built through Power Automate etc) I'll just use them. Thanks